# scrolling div height overflows footer and is hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a scroll-able div where its contents does not overflow behind the footer. There is a sidebar which has a search and another hidden div below it that shows filter options for the results displayed underneath. The results need to fill the remaining height available and scroll if there isn't enough space. At the moment it overflows so i can't see the bottom results as they are tucked behind the footer. I'm having a hard time getting the results div to only fill the remaining space.

html:

```
<div id="header">
header
</div>
  <div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map-sidebar">
      <div id="map-search">
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" />
        <div id="filters">
          <input/>
          <input/>
          <input/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map-results">
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="map"></div>  
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  footer
  </div>
```

css:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#map-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 250px;
  background: blue;
}

#map-sidebar {
   width: 250px;
   height: 100%;
}

#map-search {
    margin: 15px;
}

#map-results {
   height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

#filters {
  display: none;
}

#footer {
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JsFiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/me6nceca/

Thanks for any help

Comment: in which element do you want your scrollbars? map-results? try giving it a fixed height

Comment: in map-results correct. The height ideally needs to be dynamic as there is a button that hides and shows the filters div which will affect the height of the map-results. I could do this with javascript but if there is a css solution id prefer that.

Comment: if you test it with a fixed height and the scrollbars work then it's because the element dosn't comupte it's size correctly. probably because it's size is set to 100% and it's not the only child element of it's parent. but maybe also because the element 'map-wrapper' has no height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead in the CSS for `#map-results`:

```
height: calc(100% - 60px);
```

Comment: this will work thanks! when i display the filters i can adjust the height of the div accordingly and i need to substitute the 60px for the height of the map-search. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have set a property on all div's to have the 1 px solid red border.  Remove that from your main css and you'll see the map-results display full screen with no interference.

If you do want the red border on some divs, create a class like:

```
.redBorder {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

and add it to the divs you would like bordered.

Since you have the map set at "left: 250px;", you also will want to declare that for your footer so that it is the same width as the map (and therefore not overlapping your mapresults).  See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/me6nceca/2/

This red border may be important for you, so add that class to the specific divs you want.

CSS:

```
.redBorder {
   border: 1px solid red;
}

#map-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 250px;
  background: blue;
}

#map-sidebar {
   width: 250px;
   height: 100%;
}

#map-search {
    margin: 15px;
}

#map-results {
   height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

#filters {
  display: none;
}

#footer {
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
  right:0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 63%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
header
</div>
  <div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map-sidebar">
      <div id="map-search">
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" />
        <div id="filters">
          <input/>
          <input/>
          <input/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map-results">
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="map"></div>  
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  footer
  </div>
```

Just add that redBorder class wherever you want the red border.

Comment: The red borders were there literally to demonstrate my problem. I still want the footer to span the entire width of the body. I need the map-results to fill the remaining space.

Comment: Footer width should be set to auto

Comment: Adam, you'll need to set a height for each div then.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating this:

```
#map-results {
   height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```